# Binomial interrupting series substitution

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have a function $S(n) = \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2n}(x) dx$ and it's in this expression that I'd like to simplify ($a$ is a constant):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{1/2}{n} a^n S(n)$$

I've found a nice closed form for the following, and I was wondering if/how I could use this closed form considering the binomial is in the way.

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} t^n S(n)$$

Anything would help! I can also go into more detail on the functions if necessary :)

Comment: Just tell us what $S(n)$ is!

Answer (score 1):

Use $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {1/2 \choose k} z^k=\sqrt{1+z}-1.$$
to write $$F=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \sum_{k=1}^{n}{1/2 \choose k} a^k \sin^{2k} x dx= \int_{0}^{2\pi} [\sqrt{1+a\sin^2x}-1]~ dx=4 E(-a)-2\pi.$$
$E(-a)$ is the elliptic integral.

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy, I had a look at the *"Table of Integrals, Series and Products"* (seventh edition) by I.S. Gradshteyn and I.M. Ryzhik. Adapting equation $3.661.2$ to your case ($a=1$ and $b=0$), we have
$$S_n= \int_0^{2\pi} \sin^{2n}(x)\, dx=2 \pi\frac{  (2 n-1)\text{!!}}{(2 n)\text{!!}}=2\sqrt{\pi }\frac{  \Gamma
   \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ To make the story short, this gives the nice closed form expression you did find.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}a^n\,S_n=4E(-a)-2\pi$$  However
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^n S_n=\frac{2 \pi }{\sqrt{1-a}}-2 \pi$$ Beside the $2\pi$, I do not see what they could have in common.